# C-RET not recognized by Emacs in terminal

Tags: key-bindings, terminal-emacs

Attempting `C-c C-RET` gives me the following:

```
C-c RET is undefined
```

Any thoughts on what is happening here?

Answer (score 1):

You don't say where you are doing that. What's the current mode?

But it looks like your terminal does not support the key sequence `C-RET`, and so treats it as `RET`.

Try `C-h k C-RET`. It will likely tell you what `RET` is bound to.

Comment: Where can I find what escape keys emacs expects for each key combination? I can configure these in my terminal emulator, but I don't know what to set them to.